# Nginx sites available config not working for port 80 only

Tags: nginx, webserver, httpserver

I have setup the nginx on my server. It worked fine for port 5000. 
Now I want to setup a different server to listen to port 80. 
So I have this config, same as the first server

```
server {
    # location /etc/nginx/sites-available/backoffice
    # after creating link to sites available by
    # sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/backoffice /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

    listen 80;
    server_name backofficeX;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/backoffice_gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

It doesn't work and I get the generic **'Welcome to nginx!'** message .
The thing is, ITS not working **just for port 80** .

When I try port 5008/ 81 / ...  it works fine. What Am I missing for port 80?

I tailed the error log and the access log

`tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log`

but since there are no errors nothing comes up there

Comment: You are getting the default page because index attribute is defaulting to index.html.

Try placing an exact modifier = / { } as well.

Comment: tried looking for that config.. can you be more specific put what code exactly and where exactly to put it ?

Comment: location = / {
       include proxy_params;
       index NON_EXISTENT_FILE;
}

Comment: Thanks @RahulSoni for the reply It turns out it was the default config in a separate file.  posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don´t get mad with me, but I have to ask.

Isn't any other service running at port 80? Like apache...

Maybe you should use a port scanner to discover active ports...

Comment: I've ran `netstat -tulpn` after stopping the nginx . nothing is running on port 80

Answer (score 0):

Open your root config and ensure that you have info in error_log. This will log everything.

```
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log info;
```

Reload your configuration using **nginx -s reload**

Then see the tail of error log...

```
tail -n 100 /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

It should give you pointers about what's going on.

Comment: edited my question. there are no errors . nothing to tail. I am just getting the default nginx index.html screen instead of my app

Comment: Try placing an = / modifier in a new location block.

Answer (score 0):

Apache often runs on port 80, which might be the reason NGINX is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out what was listening on port 80 was nginx itself!!!
so I entered the default nginx file at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```
server {
    listen   4008; ## changed 80 -> 4008 (no really important what port)
```